# Async await function not executing within an event listener

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a call to the Trip Advisor API and return some data using an async/await function.

The async/await function is defined in a file named req.js and the code is below:

```
const findRest = async (reviews, closed) => {
  const respond = await fetch(
    "https://tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-by-latlng?limit=30&currency=EUR&distance=2&lunit=km&lang=en_US&latitude=53.3498&longitude=-6.2603",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "x-rapidapi-key"
      }
    }
  );

  if (respond.status === 200) {
    let data = await respond.json();
    let newData = await data.data;

    let data1 = await newData.filter(
      review => parseInt(review.num_reviews) >= reviews
    );
    let data2 = await data1.filter(close => close.is_closed == closed);
    return data2;
  } else {
    throw new Error("Could not provide results within specified parameters");
  }
};
```

This is then called when an event listener fires by clicking a button in a small form. This code is in a file named app.js and is below:

```
document.getElementById("subButton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const userReviews = parseInt(document.querySelector(".userRev").value);
  const userClose = document.querySelector(".userClose").value;

  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("click");
  console.log(e.target.id);

  findRest(userReviews, userClose)
    .then(data =>
      data.forEach(element =>
        console.log(
          `${element.name} matches your search criterea and is located at ${element.address}
        To make a booking, please call ${element.phone}`
        )
      )
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

And for reference here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>API Tester</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Phil My Glass" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="An app to help me practice my API calling"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>What Restaurant?</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <form id="form">
        <input id="userRev" class="userRev" /><br />
        <input id="userClose" class="userClose" />
        <button id="subButton" class="subButton" type="submit">Find!</button>
      </form>
    </main>
  </body>
  <script src="req.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
</html>
```

When I run the findRest function within the app.js file, but outside the event listener and pass in the arguments as static data it executes just find and prints all the requested data to the console. As soon as I try and run it within the event listener nothing happens. No returned data printing, no error and it's killing me why.

Like I said, it works fine outside the event listener, but I've tried changing the forEach to map and still nothing is being returned. Can someone please help!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-eg2yyf?file=index.js) to reproduce the issue. It is throwing issues though (no API-key) so the promise is rejected and it logs the error 'Could not provide results within specified parameters'

Comment: It throws the error because there is no api key, but as soon as I insert my api key into the code there the same thing happens and the console returns nothing.

Comment: Does the API return something? Put your debugger on `let data = await respond.json();` in the `findRest` function and see if these things actually give you a result

Comment: It does, I've just run the code in the console and seems that there is a problem with the const userClose. This seems to hold the code up for some reason and return nothing

Comment: That cannot be the case. The error is displayed when I test it without the API key so the value gets fetched without a problem. What is the output of function? Could you provide it through `const data = await findRest(userReviews, userClose); console.log(data);` or `findRest(userReviews, userClose).then((data) => console.log(data))` since you dont use async/await

Comment: I've run that code under the event listener and get the following when I click the button `Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(0)`

Comment: I think i've got the clear picture. Could you do one more logging so I can compose my answer? `if (respond.status === 200) { console.log(respond) } `. I have a feeling there are unneccesary awaits in this part.
It also appears that your data is an empty array, therefore the `map` callback is not executed

Comment: Did that and got the following `Response {type: "cors", url: "https://tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/li…=km&lang=en_US&latitude=53.3498&longitude=-6.2603", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "cors"
url: "https://tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-by-latlng?limit=30&currency=EUR&distance=2&lunit=km&lang=en_US&latitude=53.3498&longitude=-6.2603"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: true
__proto__: Response`

Comment: Could you try the functions provided in my answers and add a comment the output?

Comment: Output is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at findRest (req.js:45) (//line with return data.filter)
    at async HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:46) (//line with restaurant => on it)`

Comment: That is a mistake on my end. Please see the updated answer

Comment: The function still returns an empty array. The json data is returned though as an array of objects with all the data through the console.log command

Comment: Can you give the console output? As I stated in my answer, I suspect the boolean filter to give you issues. If you type in 'true' in the second input, it won't match the boolean filter as boolean != string

Comment: sorry, yes. The output is the following `click
app.js:50 subButton
req.js:44 {data: Array(33), open_hours_options: {…}, paging: {…}}data: (33) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]open_hours_options: {closed_count: "94", is_set: false, low_coverage_primary_message: "Open hours aren't available for all places.", timezone: "Europe/Dublin", unsure_count: "452", …}paging: {results: "30", total_results: "1142"}__proto__: Object
app.js:55 []`

Comment: I've tried adding a conditional if statement to set the userClose variable to either true or false depending on what is input by the user and changing it from const to let but this has not worked either.

Comment: `const userClose = document.querySelector(".userClose").value === 'true';`. You can also add some debugging information in your filter instead. But this is no longer an issue with the eventListener, the filtering is just wrong here. Filtering the debug has been added to the answer.

Comment: still returns an empty array - `{data: Array(33), open_hours_options: {…}, paging: {…}}
app.js:55 []` I've edited the code to return a boolean of false, but even when I do this it still returns the empty array result above

Comment: What did the console logging with the 'debug' messages

Comment: out was the following: `review debug: undefined, number -> output: false
req.js:54 closed debug: boolean, boolean -> output: true`

Comment: Aha, this means that property `num_review` does not exist on the restaurant object! Please use the correct property to compare the reviews. The issue was with your initial filter (you used num_review in the code snippet too). Please accept my answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Amazing, that was some serious detective work. Thanks! I did use `num_reviews` in my original snippet, but it wasn't returning a boolean. The new const for userClose has solved that.

Comment: Glad we got it sorted out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

Judging by the comments and your replies: the reason why nothing is a happening is because the data is an empty array.
`Array.forEach(callback)` only executes the callback when the array contains elements.

The reason why it might be empty is that the filter for `restaurant.is_closed` probably expects a boolean, whereas you pass in a string (the value of an input element is a string).

It's better to use a checkbox to see if it's checked instead. Otherwise you have to see if the string input matches with 'true' or 'false'.

## Code itself

The `findRest` contains unnecessary awaits.
You should define it as

```
async function findRest(reviews, closed) {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-by-latlng?limit=30&currency=EUR&distance=2&lunit=km&lang=en_US&latitude=53.3498&longitude=-6.2603",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "x-rapidapi-key"
      }
    }
  );

  if (response.status === 200) {
    // The only async call is casting the response to a JavaScript object
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    const data = json.data;
    // Filtering the array is not async
    return data.filter((restaurant) => {
      // Adding some additional debugs to prove my hypothesis right
      const hasEnoughReviews = restaurant.num_review >= reviews;
      const isClosed = restaurant.is_closed === closed;
      console.log(`review debug: ${typeof restaurant.num_review}, ${typeof reviews} -> output: ${hasEnoughReviews}`);
      console.log(`closed debug: ${typeof restaurant.is_closed}, ${typeof closed} -> output: ${isClosed}`)
      return hasEnoughReviews && isClosed

    })
  } else {
    throw new Error("Could not provide results within specified parameters");
  }
}
```

You can also use the async/await in your eventListener callback, creating cleaner code

```
document.getElementById("subButton").addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  const userReviews = parseInt(document.querySelector(".userRev").value);
  // Judging by the filter in the findRest, this should be a boolean?
  const userClose = document.querySelector(".userClose").value;

  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("click");
  console.log(e.target.id);

  try {
    const restaurants = await findRest(userReviews, userClose);
    // I think your issue is that restaurants is an empty array
    console.log(restaurants)
    restaurants.forEach(restaurant => {
      console.log(`${restaurant.name} matches your search criterea and is located at ${restaurant.address}
        To make a booking, please call ${restaurant.phone}`)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
});
```